# Perl regex multiline matching in an XML file with duplicate tags

Tags: xml, perl, regex-greedy

Ultimately, I'm trying to wrap all non-empty elements of the XML file in

```
'<![CDATA[...]]>'
```

Here is a sample I'm testing my code on:

```
<currentTime4 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">10:36</currentTime4>
<todayDate dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">06/02/2009</todayDate>
<todayDate3 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">06/02/2009</todayDate3>
<todayDate4 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">06/02/2009</todayDate4>
<currentTime dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">10:36</currentTime>
<Relationship dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"></Relationship>
<PatSignatureIII dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"></PatSignatureIII>
<PatSignatureIV dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"></PatSignatureIV>
<PatSignature dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">313031320D0A3</PatSignature>
<Relationship dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">Mother</Relationship>
<currentTime3 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">10:36</currentTime3>
</consent_to_treat>
```

It mimics XML that I have to deal with, but in reality, some of the elements contain multi-line text, which makes this adventure much more interesting...

I constructed a regular expression that works as long as there are no duplicates:

```
$text =~ s/(<(\w+) +[" \w\/\-=:]+?>)(?!\n)(.+?)(?<!\n)(<\/\2>)/$1<!\[CDATA\[$3\]\]>$4/gs;
```

but it fails in this example, as follows:

```
<consent_to_treat dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43" version="">
<currentTime4 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[10:36]]></currentTime4>
<todayDate dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[06/02/2009]]></todayDate>
<todayDate3 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[06/02/2009]]></todayDate3>
<todayDate4 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[06/02/2009]]></todayDate4>
<currentTime dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[10:36]]></currentTime>
<Relationship dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[</Relationship>
<PatSignatureIII dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"></PatSignatureIII>
<PatSignatureIV dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"></PatSignatureIV>
<PatSignature dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">313031320D0A3</PatSignature>
<Relationship dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">Mother]]></Relationship>
<currentTime3 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[10:36]]></currentTime3>
</consent_to_treat>
```

What is the best way to make it non-greedy, or, perhaps, a better solution different from mine?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I believe I figured it out eventually. The following code seems to do the trick:

```
$text =~ s/(<(\w+) +[" \w\/\-=:]+?>)(?!(\n|\s*<\/\2>))(.+?)(?<!\n)(<\/\2>)/$1<!\[CDATA\[$4\]\]>$5/gs;
```

Thanks again to everyone who answered my question, and I'm still open to a better solution...

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you don't want to use an XML parser for this task?

Comment: I do use it, after I fix all the issues with elements.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do what you need:

```
s/(<[^>]+>)(.*?)(<\/[^>]+>)/$1<![CDATA[$2]]>$3/gi
```

code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $xml = <<'END_XML';
<currentTime4 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">10:36</currentTime4>
<todayDate dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">06/02/2009</todayDate>
<todayDate3 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">06/02/2009</todayDate3>
<todayDate4 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">06/02/2009</todayDate4>
<currentTime dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">10:36</currentTime>
<Relationship dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"></Relationship>
<PatSignatureIII dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"></PatSignatureIII>
<PatSignatureIV dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"></PatSignatureIV>
<PatSignature dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">313031320D0A3</PatSignature>
<Relationship dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">Mother</Relationship>
<currentTime3 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43">10:36</currentTime3>
</consent_to_treat>
END_XML

$xml =~ s/(<[^>]+>)(.*?)(<\/[^>]+>)/$1<![CDATA[$2]]>$3/gi;

print $xml;
```

output :

```
<currentTime4 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[10:36]]></currentTime4>
<todayDate dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[06/02/2009]]></todayDate>
<todayDate3 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[06/02/2009]]></todayDate3>
<todayDate4 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[06/02/2009]]></todayDate4>
<currentTime dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[10:36]]></currentTime>
<Relationship dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[]]></Relationship>
<PatSignatureIII dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[]]></PatSignatureIII>
<PatSignatureIV dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[]]></PatSignatureIV>
<PatSignature dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[313031320D0A3]]></PatSignature>
<Relationship dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[Mother]]></Relationship>
<currentTime3 dsi="user 2009/06/02 10:43"><![CDATA[10:36]]></currentTime3>
</consent_to_treat>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the problem with this solution is that we would like to preserve >'s and <'s in the text between tags whenever possible, and this is the reason I'm wrapping it.

Comment: I don't Understand! What this means : `>'s and <'s`
show examples.

Comment: Here's one of them: "concentration > 2%". The text between XML tags can also contain HTML markup (<BR>, <P>, etc.)